# Push Notification in Xamarin using AWS SNS

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, amazon-sns

I provide various rental space, and my app provides the feature to rent this space to people. Let's say a user with higher priority/ memebrship in my app trying to book a space that is being used up by lower priority user. As soon as the higher priority user press the book button I want a notification to pop up in the lower priority users mobile.

My app is build using Xamarin Forms. And I want to push notification using AWS SNS, but as I see SNS requires device token to send the notification. I am planning to store the device token in the database for ever user, but I am not entirely sure how to get device token depending upon both IOS and Android environment. I am thinking of using a dependency interface that

```
public interface INotificationService
{
   Task<string> GetDeviceToken();
}
```

And I have not find a good source which I can use to get device token.

Can anyone help me, and correct me if it is correct to save device token in database?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is for iOS only and works for me.

Put this into your `AppDelegate`.

```java
public async override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData token)
{
    if (application.IsRegisteredForRemoteNotifications == true)
    {
        var snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient("your aws key id", "your aws secret key", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.YourRegion);

        /* In the AWS SNS example here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-sns-ios.html
           token.Description is used, for me the line below triggers an exception, so I used token.DebugDescription instead.
        */
        var deviceToken = token.DebugDescription.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace(" ", "");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceToken))
        {
            //register with SNS to create an endpoint ARN
            var response = await snsClient.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(
            new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest
            {
                Token = deviceToken,
                PlatformApplicationArn = "your aws platform application arn"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As for storing it in a database, I haven't got that far, but I am think of using DynamoDB for my specific purpose.

Comment: You may find this article useful too. It is Azure specific, but does contain lots of helpful information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms#configure-the-native-ios-project-for-push-notifications